# Stream and Task Stored procedure example, I am not sure how to troubleshoot the javascript

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have just learned about Streams and Tasks in Snowflake and have tested the example for tracking members and sign ups [in the first example here.](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/streams.html#examples)

I have attempted to create a stored procedure that looks like this:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure member_update()
   returns string not null
   language javascript
   as 
   $$
   var statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "BEGIN"} );
   statement.execute();
   var statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "UPDATE members SET fee = fee + 15 where fee > 0"} );
   statement.execute();

   var statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "SELECT * FROM member_check"} );
   statement.execute();

   var statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "COMMIT"} );
   statement.execute();

   var statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "SELECT * FROM member_check"} );
   statement.execute();

   $$
   ;
   
   
INSERT INTO members (id,name,fee)
VALUES
(11,'Bill',0),
(12,'Jason',0),
(13,'Suzan',0),
(14,'Michelle',0),
(15,'AARON',0);


SELECT * FROM MEMBER_CHECK;

INSERT INTO signup
VALUES
(11,'2018-01-01'),
(12,'2018-02-15'),
(13,'2018-05-01'),
(14,'2018-07-16'),
(15,'2018-08-21');

MERGE INTO members m
  USING (
    SELECT id, dt
    FROM signup s
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, '2018-08-15'::date, s.dt::DATE) < -30) s
    ON m.id = s.id
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET m.fee = 90;   
  
Call member_update();
```

I have run into an error and was hoping I might get some guidance on by very beginner stored procedure.

Error:

> Execution error in store procedure MEMBER_UPDATE: empty argument
>   passed At Snowflake.createStatement, line 2 position 29

Comment: Try changing SqlTxt to sqlText

Comment: and currently transaction management is not allowed in Stored Procedures https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html

Comment: @Erick That would explain "NULL result in a non-nullable column", is this a feature that is being considered?

Comment: @waldente thank you, I missed that.

Comment: I now see you mean "UPDATE, Insert, etc"  as the issue.

Comment: Yes, I believe transaction management is in preview